# Where can I find information on the sixth normal form

Tags: sql, database, database-design, 6nf

I am looking for information on how to implement the sixth normal form. I have searched everywhere online without success. I would like to see an example how how is implemented and designed. It would especially help if there are any books or documentation on how to implement it.

Comment: Just after the information on fifth normal form. Why on earth would you want such a thing?

Comment: Looks like you need to read C.J. Date *et al.*, *Temporal Databases* etc., 2003.

Answer (score 5):

Since you've searched everywhere, you've probably searched [dba.stackexchange.com](https://dba.stackexchange.com/) too... But if you did not, see [6th normal form, Recomposition query, efficient implementation](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/8994/6th-normal-form-recomposition-query-efficient-implementation).

They refer to chapter 7 of [An Introduction to Relational Database Theory (4th Ed.) by Hugh Darwen](http://bookboon.com/en/textbooks/it-programming/an-introduction-to-relational-database-theory).